# Carousel responsive con Bootstrap no me muestra imagen completa

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy realizando un Carousel pero a la hora de hacerlo responsive no se muestra la imagen completa al poner el navegador en modo responsive, si se adapta al tamaño movil pero solo se muestra un pequeño pedazo de la imagen, es posible que la imagen se muestre completa a la vez que se adapte al tamaño movil? 
Este es mi codigo de mi carousel:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 auto mt-3">
                <div class="carousel slide" id="principial-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#principial-carousel" data-slid-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#principial-carousel" data-slid-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#principial-carousel" data-slid-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img src="imagenes/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img src="imagenes/2.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img src="imagenes/3.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <a href="#principial-carousel" class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#principial-carousel" class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Necesitamos un ejemlo replicable para poder detectar el error, de esta manera no podemos ayudarte (solo con la estructura `html`), pero puedes agregar los `css` o armar un `test` para que podarmos replicarlo.

Comment: Indica también, por favor, que versión de `Bootstrap` estás usando. Mientras tanto, puedes probar agregando esta clase: `<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">` y en tu `CSS` deberías tener esto: `.img-fluid{ max-width: 100%; height: auto;}`

Comment: @DjCrazy está utilizando la versión 4

Comment: Marco te recomiendo agregues a las imágenes la clase `.img-fluid`. Cuéntanos cómo te va con eso.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a añadir `width:100%!important` que se añade con la clase 'w-100' de bootrstrap

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 auto mt-3">
                <div class="carousel slide" id="principial-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#principial-carousel" data-slid-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#principial-carousel" data-slid-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#principial-carousel" data-slid-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="w-100" src="imagenes/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="w-100" src="imagenes/2.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="w-100" src="imagenes/3.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <a href="#principial-carousel" class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#principial-carousel" class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A las imágenes del carrusel le faltan las clases `d-block` y `w-100`. Las dos te van a servir para que ellas tomen el tamaño completo del contenedor en el que están, y para prevenir el alineamiento de la imagen por defecto de tu navegador.

```
<img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="">
```

Aplicado a tu carrusel, queda así:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div> <!-- Contenedor del carrusel. Prueba aquí las clases de tamaño que necesites -->
  <div class="carousel slide" id="principial-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#principial-carousel" data-slid-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#principial-carousel" data-slid-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#principial-carousel" data-slid-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    
    <!-- Para probar el funcionamiento, estoy poniendo imágenes "holder" de ancho de 1000px. -->

    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x200?text=Imagen del carrusel 1" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x200?text=Imagen del carrusel 2" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x200?text=Imagen del carrusel 3" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#principial-carousel" class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#principial-carousel" class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Véase también:** Artículo de [Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/) en la documentación oficial de Bootstrap 4 (en inglés).